# Error while rendering view: '/Views/SxaLayout/SxaLayout.cshtml' on CD but not on CM

Tags: sxa

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1.
I have a scaled environment.
I have multiple sites: one shared site where I have my rendering variants, and another two sites.

I'm using **query** in the rendering variants data source in order to use it across multiple sites, as shown in below image.

[image]

The problem now is, the published site suddenly gave me the below error. After some investigations I found out that "query" is the reason, it somehow gives a null reference exception, as whenever I remove it the CD works just fine and error disappears.

[image]

Below is the error appearing in log files

```
8808 14:06:09 ERROR Failed to render rendering
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/SxaLayout/SxaLayout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').


 Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_SxaLayout_Bootstrap4Body_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitesc.sc\Views\SxaLayout\Bootstrap4Body.cshtml:line 17
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services.RazorService.GetRazorViewAsString(Object model, String filePath)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Extensions.GridExtensions.GridBody(RazorExtensions helper)
   at ASP._Page_Views_SxaLayout_SxaLayout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitesc.sc\Views\SxaLayout\SxaLayout.cshtml:line 55
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

The point is, everything is working in cm. I tried to republish all sites and everything in the cm multiple times but no luck.

Any idea what might be the reason for this error? mentioning that it was already working before.

Comment: Do you use somewhere else query and it works on CD? Do you have elsewhere $site in the query? Can $site cause your issue? Can you create different query without $site? Is it working without it?

Comment: Based on the error logs, it looks like the issue is with the SOLR indexes. See if the blow links help you :
1. https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/8121
2. https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2019/07/04/pay-attention-to-your-index-exclusions/
Try checking what you're excluding from indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it can be seen that there is problem with SOLR index. Can you try rebuilding the Sitecore_Web_Index and in case you are using any custom index for CD and have exclude the tree from Web index then you will need to include it.

Hope it helps.